# iOS - How to re-load a different ViewController within a UITabBar

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a `UITabBar`. The `TabBar` has 2 tabs:
Tab1: has `NavigationController` with root view as `HomeViewController`
Tab2: has `AboutViewController` and has a button on the view

When user clicks on button(on the `AboutViewController`), how can I programmatically re-load and display the `HomeViewController` again?

Im using `iOS6`

Comment: Why don't you just switch back to tab 1?

Comment: Ok, that helps. I should of mentioned the HomeViewController's init method will load data from a web service. How can I call the init method as well when the view shows?

Answer (score 1):

UITabBar has a method `[setSelectedIndex]`